# Enabling nullable types makes no difference

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types

I had some issues with enabling non-nullable reference types. Not sure if it's an actual issue or if it's me that isn't keeping up with the latest naming / setup of this.

This is my current setup (using VS Code):

```
Dotnet version: 3.0.100-preview6-012264
Omnisharp: 1.20.0
```

I noticed that the flag for enabling nullable has changed multiple times but as I could see in documentation, and on the internet, latest seemed to be `<Nullable/>` which I enabled in all (both main web project shown below and in my .NET Standard 2.0 class libs):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  ...

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>8.0</LangVersion>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <WarningsAsErrors>CS8600;CS8602;CS8603</WarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

If I use `#nullable enable` in the file I'm testing, I see that the IntelliSense switches directly to, what seems to be, the right alerts. Adding this in the file will also make the build fail (which is the behavior I'm seeking).

What am I missing here to get this working on the project level?

Comment: Why are you testing preview features that barely work in VS in VS Code?

Comment: To start out, i get the same problem in VS 2019 16.1.3 as i get in vs code. But regarding why: 

Mainly testing / learning purpose, i like many of the new added stuff in c# 8 (and especially non-nullable reference types). 
I also have a small, longer term, personal project i would like to adopt these features on directly (since c# 8 and net core 3 will roll out later this year).

Comment: If it's the same proble, that CSPROJ config is probably not correct. You say it's the latest you find, but is the .NET Core SDK version the latest? What about the supporting tooling?

Comment: My dotnet version (3.0.100-preview6-012264) is the latest listed here: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0
The omnisharp version im using should be the latest version according to https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/releases (im using 1.20.0).

 I also run in VS with SDK previews enabled but im NOT using the VS preview version as the dotnet site recommends (have only stable VS installed currently).

Comment: So it MIGHT be that if i installed VS preview it would work. But then again my goal was to get this running in VS Code (if possible within reasonable parameters). And i normally default to VS Code at home, not VS.

BTW: The project im testing this on is more or less a helloworld. So the project file you see above is the entire thing, apart from two references to class libraries (that are empty). I duplicated the LangVersion, Nullable and WarningsAsErrors to the classlibs csprojs as well and it all compiles fine (but totally ignores code that violates non-nullable reference types).

Comment: Will install VS preview as well, just for comparison, and see if it works there. Might be (as i interpreted you indicate), that this not yet supported / works fully for vs code / omnisharp perhaps?

Ive seen they have done work on this earlier (https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/pull/1404) btw. So i assume it is underway if not already working in some configuration (and yes i tried the old property naming as well ;) ).

Comment: Well, I'm surprised anything of C# 8 works in VSCode. Install VS Preview as that might have a newer tooling (or even tooling that's only enabled in VS Preview)

Comment: Perhaps you need `<NullableContextOptions>enable</NullableContextOptions>` instead?

Comment: @NetMage You are probably right, looking at https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/pull/1404/files#diff-1a236a8c98abe2a673cb404181c1de39R7

Comment: NetMage: I actually tried that (and the naming, they used before that, they seems to have changed the name at least two times) but did not help. Will try it again to be sure though.

Comment: @NetMage thank you for pushing me to test this again.

NullableContextOptions does in fact work. But first time i tried that one i did not include WarningsAsErrors so it just built and ran with the warnings noted in terminal.

Comment: Did not notice it earlier since i the intellisense still showed lines like 'string test = null;' invalid and it ran fine (so did not go through terminal warnings). Disabled a c# related extension i had and restarted VS Code and now intellisense seems OK as well. Thanks guys for your input :).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To summarize the discussion above:

The naming of this currently differs between omnisharp (vs code) and when using Visual Studio it seems. So the MS documentation, which specifies `<Nullable>` is not applicable. For omnisharp / vs code `<NullableContextOptions>enable</NullableContextOptions>` needs to be used instead (until omnisharp has been updated).